# Install Alongside Windows option missing

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, windows-8

I had Ubuntu 14.04 installed on my system, which I replaced with Windows 8.1.
Now, I'm trying to re-install Ubuntu to dual boot with Windows.
However, the installer is not detecting Windows, and the only options I'm seeing are to erase disk and install Ubuntu, or the something else.

I tried what [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/289233/272035) answer says, but fixparts exits with the message

> "This disk appears to be a GPT disk. Use GNU Parted or GPT fdisk on it!"

Edit : Running gdisk doesn't show any errors, but does give the following message :

> Partition table scan:
> MBR: protective
> BSD: not present
> APM: not present
> GPT: present
>
> Found valid GPT with protective MBR; using GPT.

I think this might be because fixparts is somehow detecting the previous Ubuntu partitions that Windows overwrote.
My current partitions look like this [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8r5Xj.jpg) (/dev/sda4 is the windows partition, the 38 GB unallocated space is where I'd like to install ubuntu):

So, what should I do?

Can I just use "Something Else" and install Ubuntu to the unallocated space by creating ext4 partitions there? And if I do that, how will I boot to windows, because the new bootloader will probably not include a windows entry as Ubuntu hasn't detected it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Install alongside" option missing. How do I install Ubuntu beside Windows using "Something Else"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/163962/install-alongside-option-missing-how-do-i-install-ubuntu-beside-windows-using)

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete all the partitions using linux disc.
2. Try windows disc > create partion as you need for windows(leave the remaining area un-partitioned) > install windows and all it's components > reboot and verify.
3. Try linux disc > use un-partitioned area and kept other partition intact > install linux > reboot in windows then reboot in linux and verify.