# how can i install ubuntu 14.4 LTS from windows 7 using windows installer?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, 14.04, system-installation

when i tried to install ubuntu from bootable USB it couldn't recognize my installed windows 7 so it showed me like i have to erase my whole drive and then ubuntu can be installed. please help me with this ASAP.

Comment: There are many threads about this issue. Did you put any effort in looking for existing answers?

Comment: Check [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/319792/ubuntu-does-not-recognize-existing-windows-partitions-in-a-gpt-disk#319856)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, This should not be a problem.

First try with `wubi` which comes with Ubuntu 1404 LTS CD. Inside there `wubi` icon can be found. Once you double click it, it will starts the installation as a normal windows program. But what this does is that it installs the Ubuntu on the system as a dual boot  instead as a program inside the windows. Thats all..

When system rebooting it will give you list of OS to select.

Answer (score 0):

In the Ubuntu terminal, execute the command line below:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Then reboot the system, then you could see the boot menu options including both windows7 and ubuntu.

Please refer to:

[Problems installing and dual booting Ubuntu 12.4, 13.10, and 14.4.1 via pendrivelinux?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/589591/problems-installing-and-dual-booting-ubuntu-12-4-13-10-and-14-4-1-via-pendrive/662393#662393)